# sql: how to correctly form a where clause with so many ands

Tags: sql

The following is ignoring the date range. Please could someone explain what is going wrong here? Not sure if some of the statement requires parenthesis around it but wouldn't understand why anyhow.

```
WHERE
     booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
 AND booking_status = 'Confirmed'
  OR booking_status = 'Cancelled'
  OR booking_status = 'Rearranged'
 AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
WHERE booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
AND (booking_status = 'Confirmed' OR booking_status = 'Cancelled' OR booking_status = 'Rearranged')
AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC"
```

The added line breaks are just for easier reading. The important part is the parentheses.

Take a look at this page for an explanation of operator precedence: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Put parenthesis around your `OR` conditions:

```
WHERE
     booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
 AND (booking_status = 'Confirmed'
      OR booking_status = 'Cancelled'
      OR booking_status = 'Rearranged')
 AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC
```

You could also use `IN` which might be easier to read and understand:

```
WHERE
     booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
 AND booking_status IN ('Confirmed', 'Cancelled', 'Rearranged')
 AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

AND has higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) than OR. Your code is being interpreted as:

```
WHERE (booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
       AND booking_status = 'Confirmed')
OR (booking_status = 'Cancelled')
OR (booking_status = 'Rearranged' AND invoice_number='')
```

Instead of using OR, I'd suggest using IN:

```
WHERE booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21'
AND booking_status IN ('Confirmed', 'Cancelled', 'Rearranged')
AND invoice_number=''
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely, the In operator is most efficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your `OR` that's giving you issues:

To reformat:

```
WHERE booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21' 
AND (booking_status = 'Confirmed' 
    OR booking_status = 'Cancelled' 
    OR booking_status = 'Rearranged') 
AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC
```

You can add parentheses to make it do what you want (as above), or you could even use an `IN` clause:

```
WHERE booking_date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-21' 
AND booking_status IN ( 'Confirmed', 'Cancelled', 'Rearranged') 
AND invoice_number=''
ORDER BY booking_date ASC
```